# pdfminer extracted text contains CID characters

Tags: python, pdf, text, pdfminer

I am trying to extract a pdf to txt file. The output file is quite succesful except some sentences have characters like  (CID:number). At first i thought it was because of turkish characters but they turn out okay. For example in the following sentence

*(cid:54)u sıcaklığı*

first character is s (lower case). So i couldnt understand why the other "s" are normal. Can anyone explain? How can i solve ?

Here is the function i am using

```
def pdfparser(data):
fp = open(data, 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
retstr = io.StringIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    data = retstr.getvalue()

print(data)
```

Comment: Can you provide your code and a sample PDF file

Comment: Indeed, issues like that usually are due to weirdnesses in the respective pdfs.

Comment: I added my code, thank you .

Comment: To tell why one would need to look at the character map in the font that the PDF is using for the text. It does this when there are alternate glyphs for which the font does not include a character code to unicode mapping

Comment: How to work around this problem? Is there a solution? @DanD.